# Stamina regeneration not doing as intended

Tags: roblox

I'm trying to make it so that whenever the player stands still they regenate stamina faster than if they are walking. So far the stamina bar only goes up but not down. I got it to work before but that was only with the W key now I'm trying to make it detect WASD.

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local char = player.Character

local UIS = game:GetService("UserInputService")

local stamina = 250
local isRunning = false
local isMoving = false
local isMovingW = false
local isMovingA = false
local isMovingS = false
local isMovingD = false


stamina = math.clamp(stamina, 0, 250)

UIS.InputBegan:Connect(function(input)
    if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.W then
        isMovingW = true

    end
end)

UIS.InputBegan:Connect(function(input)
    if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.A then
        isMovingA = true

    end
end)

UIS.InputBegan:Connect(function(input)
    if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.S then
        isMovingS = true

    end
end)

UIS.InputBegan:Connect(function(input)
    if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.D then
        isMovingD = true

    end
end)

if isMovingW == true or isMovingA == true or isMovingS == true or isMovingD == true then
    isMoving = true
end

UIS.InputEnded:Connect(function(input)
    if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.W then
        isMovingW = false
    end
end) 

UIS.InputEnded:Connect(function(input)
    if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.A then
        isMovingA = false
    end
end) 

UIS.InputEnded:Connect(function(input)
    if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.S then
        isMovingS = false
    end
end) 

UIS.InputEnded:Connect(function(input)
    if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.D then
        isMovingD = false
    end
end) 

if isMovingW == false and isMovingA == false and isMovingS == false and isMovingD == false then
    isMoving = false
end

UIS.InputBegan:Connect(function(input)
    if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.LeftShift then
        isRunning = true
        char.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = 32

        while stamina > 0 and isRunning do
            stamina = stamina -1
            script.Parent:TweenSize(UDim2.new(stamina/250, 0, 1, 0), "Out", "Linear",0)
            wait()
            if stamina <= 0 then
                char.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = 16
            end

        end
    end
end)

UIS.InputEnded:Connect(function(input)
    if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.LeftShift then
        isRunning = false
        char.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = 16

        while stamina < 250 and isMoving == true and not isRunning do
            stamina = stamina +0.5
            script.Parent:TweenSize(UDim2.new(stamina/250, 0, 1, 0), "Out", "Linear",0)
            wait()

            while   stamina < 250 and isMoving == false and not isRunning do
                stamina = stamina +1
                script.Parent:TweenSize(UDim2.new(stamina/250, 0, 1, 0), "Out", "Linear",0)
                wait()

                if stamina == 0 then
                    char.Humanoid.Walkspeed = 16

                end
            end
        end
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is surely not the best solution, but you could check for the player position changing instead of checking for WASD.

Something like this should work (if you decide to use this, delete your old detection for movement):

```
--put this at the beginning of the script

local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local char = player.Character or player.CharacterAdded:Wait()
local humanoid = char:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
local root = char:FindFirstChild("HumanoidRootPart")

--put this after the rest of your code

while true do 
    pos1 = root.Position
    wait(0.001) --you can lower this if you want it to be more accurate, but it will cause intense lag
    pos2 = root.Position
    if pos1 ~= pos2 then
        isMoving = true
    end
end
```